# In diophantine $3b^2=a^2$ where $a$ and $b$ are coprime, does $3|a$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Integers $a$ and $b$ are co-prime and $3\cdot b^2=a^2$.

$3\cdot b^2=a^2$, implies $a^2$ is divisible by 3 since, $3b^2$ is divisible by 3.

Is $a$ divisible by 3?

Comment: you don't even need $a$ and $b$ to be coprime to deduce. Since $3\mid a^2$, it automatically divides $a$.

By the way, I think you're trying to prove that $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, $a$ must be divisible by $3$. If the integer $a=3k+1$ or $3k+2$ for arbitrary $k$, (which are the cases in which $a$ is not divisible by $3$) then the remainder is $9k^2+6k+1\equiv1\pmod3$ or $9k^2+12k+4\equiv1\pmod3$.

Therefore, $a^2|3$ cannot occur if $a$ is not divisible by $3$, and thus, $a$ must be divisible by $3$.

However, the equation $3a^2=b^2$ cannot be solved for coprime integers, so if you consider that, then it is impossible for $a|3$ since there are no $a$ that fit the equation.

Answer (score 2):

Yep; in general, if $p|ab$ then $p|a$ or $p|b$ ($p$ is a prime). In your case, $3|a^2$ so $3|a$ or $3|a$; thus $a$ is divisible by $3$

Answer (score 1):

*THEOREM*: In general, if $p$ is prime and $p|n^2$, then $p|n$, where $n$$\in$$Z$.

The proof is based on the uniqueness of prime factorisation.

In your case, $3$ is a prime and $a$ is an integer.
Since $3|a^2$, this implies that $3|a$

Comment: Even more general is the fact that, if $m$ is **squarefree** and $m \mid n^2$, then $m \mid n$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $:$ Let $p$ be a prime number and $a,b$ be positive integers such that $p \mid ab.$ Then either $p \mid a$ or $p \mid b.$